# Why do I see third party packages in my Azure Artifacts feed?

Tags: azure-devops

I have a build pipeline setup creating packages from my projects, and a release pipeline that is pushing those packages to the artifact feed, but now (after some change to the pipeline) I'm seeing microsoft packages in my feed.

Any info about why this is happening would be great.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NuGet.org is an [upstream source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/concepts/upstream-sources?view=vsts). Your feed is configured to use nuget.org as an upstream source, so it's caching the packages from nuget.org that your applications are using.

Comment: Does removing the upstream source cause builds to fail, or is it just allowing feed consumers to get to those packages through my artifact feed?

Comment: It depends on your NuGet.config. If you depend on a single source and that source is your package management feed, then yes, builds will fail without an upstream source.